# The correct term for little pieces of rubbish of all sorts found on the floor

Tags: terminology

There are always little pieces of rubbish found on the floor, which means when you clean the floor, dust is not the only "rubbish" that you have to get rid of. What is the correct term for those little pieces of rubbish? Maybe "bits", "detritus" or "scraps"? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is one 'correct' term. All your suggestions would be OK.

Comment: Probably [debris](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/debris) can also be used.

Comment: _Lint_ might be another item.

Comment: Of course, a lot of people would call it, er, "sith".